# How to connect to a public node through json RPC?

Tags: json-rpc, php

I found a list of public bitcoin nodes [here](https://bitnodes.earn.com/nodes/).  I am using a php [library](https://github.com/aceat64/EasyBitcoin-PHP). How can I connect to these nodes via JSON RPC? Is it safe to connect to public nodes? What should I give as username and password?

I had tried a bitcoin node on my ec2 instance. It is taking too long to sync and blockchain size is also increasing. I want to communicate with bitcoin network without running a bitcoin daemon.

Answer (score 2):

Not all nodes will have the JSON-RPC enabled, and especially without private credentials. You will probably find a block explorer API much more accessible, because they are built to handle public traffic. There are many blockchain explorers online that have public apis, they are easy to find.

Comment: actually I need to generate address and push transactions into the blockchain.. most blockchain explorers give block height and related info.. iam new to cryptocurrencies so i might be incorrect

Comment: You can run an SPV node (light node)

Comment: You'd be very foolish to trust a random node in the network to make private keys for you.